# Drawing pentagon with asteriks on the console

Tags: console, ascii-art

I am drawing a triangle with asteriks on the console with for loops by taking the coordinates from the user.but I couldn't draw pentagon.pentagon includes 3 triangle but the program i wrote couldn't attach these triangles.It is drawing 3 different triangle in different place on console.How can I solve this problem?Can you help me?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far - from your description, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible approaches for this.

1. Either you create an internal representation of the output (like a two-dimensional character array) in which you draw the graphics.

   When the image is done, you print the whole array.
2. You use escape sequences (which are specific to your terminal) to move the cursor to a certain place to draw characters.

   In your case, you should clear the terminal once and then move the cursor for each asterisk.

[EDIT] As for #1:

```
char[][] screen = new char[20][]; // 20 lines
for(int i=0;i<screen.length; i++) screen[i] = new char[80]; // 80 columns
```

Now you can draw something with `screen[y][x] = '*'`

To print:

```
for(int i=0;i<screen.length; i++) System.out.print(new String(screen[i]));
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Escape sequences are a feature of the terminal, not the language you use to access it. The difference between C++ and Java is that there are existing libraries like ncurses (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) to draw on a terminal.